# Error Loading Views After Changing Route Value of module.config.php - Zend Framework

Tags: url-routing, zend-framework2

This question is regarding Zend Framework application version: 2.1.3. I, the developer, am new to Zend Framework and would greatly value your assistance.

I was making a module for a 'Donor Management System' of a church. The module I am working on is called the 'QueryBuilder'. Previous modules were fine and works great. I use the Zend Helper for Sublime Text and it generated some thing similar for the module.config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * @package QueryBuilder
 */
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'QueryBuilder\Controller\QueryBuilder' => 'QueryBuilder\Controller\QueryBuilderController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'querybuilder' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/querybuilder[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'QueryBuilder\Controller\QueryBuilder',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                        //'action'     => 'search',
                        //'action'     => 'recent',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'querybuilder' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

Determined to have a little bit of fun after making some successful modules, I changed the `router` as follows.

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * @package QueryBuilder
 */
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'QueryBuilder\Controller\QueryBuilder' => 'QueryBuilder\Controller\QueryBuilderController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'querybuilder' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/query-builder[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'QueryBuilder\Controller\QueryBuilder',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                        //'action'     => 'search',
                        //'action'     => 'recent',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'querybuilder' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

Note: Only the `route` value was changed from `/querybuilder...` to `/query-builder...`. When I tried to access the route `http://konnections/query-builder` I got some error but I didn't go through it.

Wondering why I wan't to be a hero, I changed the value back to its defaults. And tried to load `http://konnections/querybuilder` but it also gave an error.

`Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "query-builder/query-builder/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file`

No where in the code of the module you could find the words `query-builder`. So common sense says there can be no way `query-builder/query-builder/index` needs to be accessed.

Thinking it might be some caching, I looked for it in the entire application folder. Then I restarted Apache, the computer, deleted and made a new Module with the same name `QueryBuilder` and still the error is there.

**Note**: This is a plugin that was done nothing with. I only changed the `route` value thinking it will make the URL look neater.

Here is what I end up with [Image]:
[image: The Error I get accessing the route]

Nope, this is not IE, because I tried in Chrome (which didn't access the `query-builder` url) as well.

The whole of Zend Folder (the root of the website) has no reference to `query-builder`. Where does it come from and how can I change it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I found what is going on, but am open for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

from ZF1 series (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.basics.html), ZF2 is the same but not found this description on manual.

Case Naming Conventions
Since humans are notoriously inconsistent at maintaining case sensitivity when typing links, Zend Framework actually normalizes path information to lowercase. This, of course, will affect how you name your controller and actions... or refer to them in links.
If you wish to have your controller class or action method name have multiple MixedCasedWords or camelCasedWords, you will need to separate those words on the url with either a '-' or '.' (though you can configure the character used).
As an example, if you were going to the action in FooBarController::bazBatAction(), you'd refer to it on the url as /foo-bar/baz-bat or /foo.bar/baz.bat.

Answer (score 0):

I am Ziyan, the one who asked the question in the first place.

After not finding a solution in Google, I wondered in to making another module and ended up with the same plight. Confused I made a new installation of Zend Framework and made a module with the same name.

`Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "query-builder/query-builder/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file` did not go away.

Knowing it is not some thing like reconfiguration, I looked closer.

It seemed to put a dash between every word. I was like Zend is insane! But no, it seems to be splitting the Module name from each upper case letter and adjoining them using a '-' (dash).

In my case `QueryBuilder` becomes `query-builder` or plugin named `HelloModules` would be `hello-modules`.

So the view manager seems to be looking for `../views/query-builder/query-builder/index`.

In my case, ZF Helper for Sublime text needs to look in to the situation. If you could fix the plugin at GitHub it would be great. I will give a try my self.

I couldn't find any proof for my claiming and no time to go through the source codes. Would be glad if some one provide some links.